# Input dataset of different shapes in tf.keras.Model with custom train_step override

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I defined a custom `tf.keras.Model` and overrode `train_step` for implementing custom training logic. The dataset `trainDataset` is a `tf.data` object, each element containing `(image, label)` with different image sizes. I would like to perform data augmentation inside the `train_step` as in the code below. I believe my code including the part has no logical flaws, including the part where I use model.fit to train the model.

However, an error occurs telling me that it `Cannot batch tensors with different shapes`. I see that something is executed before `train_step` and that is blocking the training process. How could I solve this?

```
model=GeneralCNN(cfg, network, augmentation)
model.compile(optimizer, loss, cfg['training'])
...
trainLogs=model.fit(trainDataset.batch(cfg['batch_size']), epochs=1, validation_data=valDataset)
```

```
...(subclass of tf.keras.Model)
def train_step(self, data):
        tf.print('check!')
        images, labels =  data
        images = self.augmentation(images) # <--- includes resizing
        # initialize important variables.
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]

        # Train the network 
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.network(images)
            loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.network.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.network.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.lossMetric.update_state(loss)

        predictionsIndicies=tf.math.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        self.accuracyMetric.update_state((predictionsIndicies, labels))
        return {"loss": self.lossMetric.result(), "accuracy": self.accuracyMetric.result()}
...
```

Error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 116, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 76, in main
    trainLogs=model.fit(P, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=1000, validation_data=valDataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3024, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1961, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [375,500,3] and element 1 had shape [333,500,3].
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at train.py:76) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1852]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Edit: augmentation code just in case

- the code works when I resize the dataset before `model.fit`

```
def BuildAugmentation(cfg):
    augmentationType = cfg['augmentation']

    if augmentationType=='none':
        return SimpleResize(cfg)
    elif augmentationType=='simple':
        return SimpleAugmentation(cfg)

def SimpleResize(cfg):
    # resizing only w/o augmentations
    model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tfPreprocessing.Resizing(cfg['image_size'], cfg['image_size'])
    ])
    return model

def SimpleAugmentation(cfg):
    # custom simple augmenation w/ humble augmentations
    model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tfPreprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.02),
        tfPreprocessing.RandomZoom(height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2),
        tfPreprocessing.Resizing(cfg['image_size'], cfg['image_size']),
        tfPreprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal")
    ])
    return model
```

Comment: In your error stack one error msg says ` First element had shape [375,500,3] and element 1 had shape [333,500,3].` , are you sure your images are of the same size even after augmentation ?

Comment: @AtharvaGundawar The problem is that the code crashes before executing `train_step`, as the third line `tf.print('check!')` is not printed.

Comment: The crash seems to happens under some function(?) named `train_function` not `train_step`. The model seems to fundamentally deny dataset with different sizes